# TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined node.js V12.18.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my first question on here so I apologize if I miss some information/formating.
I am unable to understand why my Node.js doesn't seem to work on my laptop, but works perfectly fine on another computer. This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
const random = require("./random.js");
const constants = require("./constants.js");
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');


//Listener event for when the bot sends a ready event (ex: logging in)
client.on('ready', () => {
     console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 });

 //Listener Event which runs whenever a message with prefix '!' is received
client.on('message', message => {

     var msg = message.content.toLowerCase(); //Turns message to uppercase, to make commands not case sensitive
     var sender = message.author; //Author of the message is set to the sender
     
     console.log(msg);
     if (!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || msg.author.bot) {return;}

     if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + 'pray')) {
          msg.reply('Your prayers have been heard... Lord Gaybel is pleased!'); 
     }
    
     if(msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "fortune")) {
           msg.reply('The fortune trumpet is not function currently... we are working hard to make sure that your fortunes are told.');
           msg.reply(random.getRandomInt(constants.MIN, constants.MAX));
     }
 });


//Discord Login Token
client.login(config.TOKEN);
```

This is the error I get:

```
c:\Users\Curtis\Documents\GitHub\MABEL-BOT\main.js:38
     if (!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || msg.author.bot) {return;}
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Curtis\Documents\GitHub\MABEL-BOT\main.js:38:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\Curtis\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

I am using Node.Js V 12.18.2 on both computers and NPM v 6.14.6

I have thought maybe it is a firewall issue on my laptop, but I wanted to get other opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because you're essentially doing `message.content.toLowerCase().content.startsWith()`

This should work:

```js
if (!msg.startsWith(config.prefix) || msg.author.bot) {return;}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought the error was larger than that!

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked and that the question has  been answered

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
`if (!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix)`, it should be
 `if (!msg.startsWith(config.prefix) ||...`, since you are already performing the step  `var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();` previously.